# Importing list of 7 .jpeg pictures (all the same size) and stacking them into a NxMx7 numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to import images to stack into a numpy array. I have something like this but is not giving me quite what I need and couldn't seem to find the answer online.

```
import easygui as eg
import cv2
openfiles1 = eg.fileopenbox("Select the files to stack",  multiple=True)
stack = np.array([])
for item in openfiles1:
    pic = cv2.imread(item)
    stack =np.dstack(pic)
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: the shape of my variable stack (stack.shape) yields (1,3216,2136) rather than (7,3216,2136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) documentation, `dstack` takes a tuple of numpy arrays as an argument. Right now, with each loop you are resetting the stack variable to be a stack with a tuple of length 1 (the one image you are currently on in the loop). Instead, you probably want something like this:

```
import easygui as eg
import cv2
openfiles1 = eg.fileopenbox("Select the files to stack",  multiple=True)
pics = []
for item in openfiles1:
    pics.append(cv2.imread(item))
stack = np.dstack(tuple(pics))
```

This creates a list of the arrays that you want to join (which you turn into an immutable tuple later).